# How to set animation in candle stick chart?

Tags: android

https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/18baaeb18bce1fe343f048941ce20eca/070110.mp4

How to create candlestick chart using JSON file data and also set color or round edges and this type of animation is compulsory to add in chart and chart in android studio (Java language) using any dependency like above link.